# Working in 2 different states: does the California income tax rate only consider the money earned in California, or anywhere?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, california, state-income-tax

For example, let's take Bob who:

- worked from January to March in California, where he earned 30kUSD (W2 income and Bob was a California resident),
- worked for the rest of the year in the state of Washington, where he earned 70kUSD (W2 income and Bob was a Seattle resident).

Which income tax rate should Bob use when paying taxes to California? Does he only pay state taxes on 30kUSD toward California? Or does the fact that he earned 70kUSD on the same year in some other state impact his California income tax rate?

Comment: During the time Bob is working in Washington does California still consider Bob a resident? If Bob didn't meet the California requirements for making that break they they will consider all the income taxable in California.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: It's also possible for Bob to work in California (or other states) while being a resident of a differeent state.  I've done it, and I don't remember the California nonresident tax forms asking for total income.  However, that was more than a decade ago, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @jamesqf: California nonresident tax forms ask for total income, since it uses the federal AGI which is total income for a US resident (and if you're a nonresident alien it asks you to adjust federal income to reflect worldwide income)

Comment: @mhoran_psprep During the time Bob is working in Washington, California doesn't consider Bob a California  resident.

Comment: @user102008 thank you, does this mean that whether California consider Bob a California resident during his time in Washington doesn't impact Bob's California tax rate? Or does being a California resident while working in Washington means that the 70kUSD he earned in Washington will also be taxed by California?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: It doesn't affect the tax *rate* (on the income that is taxed), but it does affect how much income is taxed. Residents are taxed on their worldwide income, while nonresidents are only taxed on their income from that state.

Comment: @user102008 got it, thanks, very good to know!

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt: Do you mean California does not consider Bob a resident for the purposes of this question, or in general?  Because if you have the usual markers of permanent residence (house, voter registration, driver's license &c), they WILL consider you a resident.  Indeed, they have been known to get pretty aggressive about considering people there for temporary reasons to be residents.  When I worked there, rumour had it that they'd go around apartment complexes and so on looking for out-of-state plates.

Comment: @jamesqf on March 31 23:59 Bob moved from CA to WA. Not trying to cheat the system, genuinely trying to understand how to file taxes made complicated due to Intuit lobbying.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt: Not suggesting any sort of cheating, just wanting to understand the situation.  It is perfectly legal to work in California while being a resident of some other state.  E.g. for a couple of years, I spent every other M-F on site in California, other work days (and all weekends & holidays) in my home state.  So I was never a resident of California.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

California, like most states, will consider the money you earned anywhere. Your California state income tax is calculated as `(California income / total income) x tax calculated on total income`. If it were instead simply `tax calculated on California income`, you could hypothetically make a little money in nearly every state, and owe practically nothing due to standard deductions and other things, while still having a fairly high total income.

You can see this in action on [CA Form 540NR](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2019/2019-540nr.pdf) (for non-residents and part-year residents). Line 19 is your total taxable income. Line 31 calculates the tax on that. Line 35 is your California taxable income. Line 36 is your California taxable income divided by your total taxable income. Line 37 is your tax multiplied by your fraction of income from California. California has an exemption credit that is also prorated in a similar manner.

So in your example, Bob will be taxed 30% of the tax calculated on $100k. This will be more than if he had only made the $30k in California, but less than if he had made all $100k in California. As I mentioned earlier, nearly every state calculates income tax in this manner, though New Jersey is one exception that I'm aware of.

EDIT: As mhoran_psprep alluded to, this assumes that Bob truly becomes a non-resident of California. If he is just relocating to Washington temporarily, California will still consider him a resident, and he will owe California tax on all $100k. See the [California residency guidelines](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2019/2019-1031-publication.pdf).